# Can't change the list's text color to white

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a list in which I have used glyphicons, when I hover my mouse, glyphicons become black, and I want the icons to appear white. I am using bootstrap also.

List:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:5px;padding:10px;font-size:20px;;font-weight:bold;">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: css -> .navbar{
 background-color:black;
 height:80px;
}    
    a{
 color:white;
}
   .navbar li{
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:25px;
 display:visible;
}
   .navbar li:hover{
 opacity:0;
 color:white;
}
    .navbar a:hover{
 color:white; 
}

Comment: where's your styles?

Comment: Wht is this tagged Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

```css
a.glyIcon{
   color:gray !important;
 }

a.glyIcon:hover{
   color:orange !important;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:5px;padding:10px;font-size:20px;;font-weight:bold;">
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>List 1</a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>List 2</a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>List 3</a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>List 4</a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>List 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add the class name for your `<a>` tag

**html**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:5px;padding:10px;font-size:20px;;font-weight:bold;">
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="glyIcon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
a.glyIcon{
   color:black !important;
 }

a.glyIcon:hover{
   color:white !important;
 }
```

Comment: @JaicyJoseph Code Updated. Try Now

Answer (score 0):

[image: Dev Tools]

As you can see your white color is overwritten as the bootstrap selector is more specific than yours.

```
.navbar a:hover{ color:white;   }
```

Furthermore, your html does not contain the class `navbar` and thus this selector does not work, perhaps try changing the class name in the CSS to to `.navbar-nav` instead.

Comment: see the image -> i want to remove that effect@StevenTang

Comment: What image? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style on hover of that particular target element.

```css
.navbar-nav li a.glyphicon i {
  color: green;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a.glyphicon {
  color: blue;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a.glyphicon i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a class="glyphicon">
      Anchor Tag
      <i class="glyphicons">sample</i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li {
  color: #000000;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
ul li:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:5px;padding:10px;font-size:20px;;font-weight:bold;">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>text1</li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></a>text2</li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>text3</li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i></a>text4</li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i></a>text5</li>
</ul>
```

Check this one.